# python 2.4.3 subprocess check_call

Tags: python, process

I have apparently an old version of python, and when i try to use

```
subprocess.check_call(...)
```

an error is returned saying that the `check_call` doesn't exist.
Is there an equivalent? By the way... i need to understand which line is invoked when i use `subprocess.call(...)`

Comment: You can use this port https://pypi.python.org/pypi/subprocess32/

Comment: Which version of python ? check_call is for 2.5 and above

Comment: Why don't you update Python to a version released less than ten years ago?!

Comment: I can't update anything... otherwise i would have used a more recent version. The version is 2.4.3, i just need something equivalent is there a way to do that? from this documentation: https://docs.python.org/release/2.4.3/ i can't spot anything useful for the purpose.

Comment: Why not? Who can? Have you tried asking them?

Comment: I tried... is there a way to do that or not?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `call` as `check_call` is actually a wrapper for `subprocess.call()`, which exists in Python 2.4. You can write your own `check_call` function:

(Warning: this is not tested as I don't have Python 2.4):

```
class CalledProcessError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, returncode, cmd, output=None):
        self.returncode = returncode
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.output = output
    def __str__(self):
        return "Command '%s' returned non-zero exit status %d" % (self.cmd, self.returncode)

def check_call(*popenargs, **kwargs):
    retcode = subprocess.call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    if retcode:
        cmd = kwargs.get("args")
        if cmd is None:
            cmd = popenargs[0]
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    return 0
```

and instead of `subprocess.check_call(...)` you can simply call your own `check_call(...)` using the same arguments.